# How to bind Popup's (or ContextMenu's) PlacementTarget to an element within UserControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, popup, contextmenu

In a scenario like this:

```
<Grid>
...
   <local:MyControl x:Name="MyCtl" Grid.Row="1"/>
   <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ???}"/>
<Grid>
```

I need to bind PlacementTarget to a button named MyBtn **within** MyCtl. What is a cleanest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyCtl}" />
```

Comment: Of course it would work - but the Popup would pop at MyCtl coordinates, not at MyBtn. If MyCtl is Window-aligned, but MyBtn is in the center of MyCtl, I want Popup to show at MyBtn coords.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the PlacementTarget in the constructor of the code behind like this:

```
popup.PlacementTarget=MyCtl.MyBtn;
```